# fold algorithm that yields each partial result

Tags: rust

The rust standard library has a [`fold()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold) which collapses an iterator into a single result:

> ```
> let a = [1, 2, 3];
>
> // the sum of all of the elements of the array
> let sum = a.iter().fold(0, |acc, x| acc + x);
>
> assert_eq!(sum, 6);
> ```

Does the standard library have an equivalent version that yields each element? That is, something like:

```
let partial_sums = a.iter()
   .what_goes_here(0, |acc, x| acc + x)
   .collect::<Vec<_>>();
assert_eq!(partial_sums, vec![1, 3, 6]);
```

Effectively, `iter.fold(init, f)` is semantically equivalent to

```
iter
    .what_goes_here(init, f)
    .last()
    .unwrap_or(init)
```

---

For anyone in the same boat as me, I'm looking for the Rust equivalent of the C++ algorithm [`partial_sum`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sum).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want [`Iterator::scan`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.scan):

```rust
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let res = v
        .iter()
        .scan(0, |acc, &x| {
            *acc += x;
            Some(*acc)
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();
    assert_eq!(res, vec![1, 3, 6]);
}
```

Comment: Mildly annoying that the accumulator semantics are actually different between `scan` and `fold`, but I guess this lets you write a `scan` which early exits.

Comment: @Barry yeah, the `scan` API is indeed a bit unusual. I guess the ownership semantic has something to do with it. A `fold`-compatible accumulator would mean that the state is to be both returned and saved for the next iteration. So it would have to be cloneable. Instead, it has a mutable state being threaded and `Option` type to have early return ability.